# Click handler is not working on lit element

Tags: html, css, lit-element, lit

I have a lit element called `<test-logo></test-logo>` that renders a logo. When someone clicks on the logo, I want to trigger a javascript logic. I added a @click handler to the element like this

```
<test-logo @click=${this._handleClickOnLogo.bind(this)}>></test-logo>
```

Here's test-logo:

```
override render() {
   return html `<logo-icon size="40"></logo-icon>
}
```

but the click handler is not being called. Can someone please help?

Comment: You don't need to do the `.bind(this)` as Lit handles that for you. Regardless, I don't see why this wouldn't work. Can you provide some reproduction?

Comment: You are not calling the function, you are binding it. Do as Augustine Kim says, use the name of the function only.